# Real query execution time without network transfer in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

is it possible to determine SELECT execution time **without** data transfer across network ?

I am trying to optimize our queries on an remote server, which is actualy about 1000 miles away from me, and fetching even small amounts of data takes minutes to get here.

SQL Developer tells me execution time with network trasnfer time included. Same situation with '`set timing on`'.

And I'm really confused of result from `SELECT * FROM v$sql(area)`.
Results from this one are still the same, even when changing executed queries. Oracle documentation says about ELAPSED_TIME column that it includes  parsing/executing/fetching times, and also that these results are somehow accumulated.

So here comes the question: Is there any straightforward way to get the real execution time of query on the server ? Without network transfer time, no matter if the query was cached or wasn't. No averages, no estimations. Just time of the **concrete** one execution of query.

Thx in advance

Comment: And I don't mean plan costs from EXPLAIN PLAN

Comment: Connect to the DB server (SSH), open up sqlplus and execute the query.

Comment: Or, create a PL/SQL procedure, put your select in there and execute the procedure. You will transfer minimum data through the network in this way. You can even call a job to run the procedure.

Comment: Try `autotrace` using `sqlplus` http://psoug.org/reference/autotrace.html

Answer (score 5):

Oracle query execution works as producer-consumer design pattern. If network connection is "stuck" then Oracle session process gets blocked by OS. In order to avoid influence of network latency, you must execute SQL queries on the DB server directly (either from sqlplus or via PL/SQL).

Suggestion: forget about time as a metrics to optimize - look at buffer gets and disk reads, this will tell you how many memory pages had to be processed while evaluating the query. This metrics is invariant (independent) to current DB server load.

If network round-trips make significant overhead, try to change an interface. By using collections, nested tables or complex types you can reduce amount network waits.

Comment: Thx, but the actuall reason why I'm trying to solve this one is bit more deeper. It's just a part of profiling whole server side application with many layers, so we are now eliminating posible causes of our performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM MY_LARGE_TABLE WHERE ...)
```

Well, you still transfer one single number over the network but this should be negligible.

Comment: I think this aproach is questinable, because we have no idea, what optimization the server will use, because in this case it actually will not need to acces tables. It can count only by accesing indexes or statistics or whatever magic Oracle does.

Comment: You are right, Oracle may optimize the query. Then I also would propose to execute the query inside a procedure as suggested above.